# How to restart Alarm after phone Reboot?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

In my project I'm using `AlarmManager` to start a `Service` once a day. It's working fine. But it stops working when the phone reboot are restarts.
I searched through web and they suggested to start a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` action and restart the `Alarm`.
I don't know how to do that.
Please suggest me an easy way to reset the alarm. I've posted my code here.

**My Code to start Alarm**

```
Intent start_alarm=new Intent(MainPage.this,MailService.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(MainPage.this, 100, start_alarm, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000*60*60*24,pi);
```

**My AlarmService**

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId){
    super.onStart(intent,startId);

       //* My Code for sending Mail *//

   }
```

**Manifest Registeration of Service**

```
<service android:name=".MailService"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a broadcast receiver and register it on manifest with intent action_reboot, then start the alarm in onReceive method

this is how to register receiver

```
       <receiver android:name="com.packagename.RebootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

this is the receiver

```
public class RebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
{

    //start your alarm
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do I have add the same code I used before to start the alarm here @Amalo?

Comment: yes you can add the same code here but this method: onReceive is called after reboot only

Comment: Yes. You can use same code you already coded to your BroadcastReceiver implementation